# What is better, updating a notifications_count on a user table or SELECT count(*) from a notifications table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, data-modeling

I am creating a notification system inside of my rails app and I want to know what is going to work better at scale.

I can create a column for the user called `notifications_count` and `UPDATE` it every time a new notification is created and `UPDATE` it every time notifications are viewed to clear the count.

I can also run a count on the Notifications table and filter it by the `user_id` and a flag `unread`.

Notifications are going to be a big feature on this app and this table is going to grow in size really fast even for individual users.

Given that the table will eventually contain a lot of data, which approach would be best?

Is there another solution that would scale better?

Comment: btw, you can make rails do all of the bookkeeping. `counter_cache`, they call this.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Thats funny i just clicked a link that showed this and i noticed you just commented it. Thanks for the advice going to look into it.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Looks like i can't use this because you cant set the counter_cache based on a bool, i would need the unread count not the count of all notifications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a relational modeling viewpoint, having that extra column with the count would be redundant and hence bad.

However, it will make the query for the count much faster, at the price of extra work during data modifications.

I would make the decision depend on the relative frequency of queries for the count versus data modifications. If the query for the count is going to be one of your very frequent ones, I would sacrifice purity for performance.

The decision is mostly independent of the database size.